# Regular expression to extract URLs with difficult formatting

Tags: python, regex, url, hyperlink

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489731/convert-urls-into-html-links-using-sed), but more complicated.

I am trying to figure out a regex to extract URLs from a text document. The tricky thing is that some of the URLs are embedded in sentences with harder to parse formatting. Here's an example of text I would like to extract URLs from:

```
<p>There are several links of the general format http://www.foo.com/index.html.</p>
<p>There are many websites (e.g. http://www.foo.com/abc/def?a=2&b=3) that end oddly: http://www.foo.com/results</p>
```

In these examples, the first URL has a sentence-ending period immediately following the link that needs to be excluded. The 2nd link has a right parenthesis at the end of the URL, and the third ends when it hits an HTML tag.

For my purposes, a period (and right parenthesis) is a valid URL character unless it is the very last character. The problem in short is how to deal with characters that are valid in a string, only if they are not the very last character in the string.

My current regex that is unable to deal with this case is (in Python):

```
m = re.findall("((http:|https:)//[^ \<]+)",line)
```

Any thoughts on elegant ways to deal with this?

Comment: Possibly you want one of these

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forbid period as the last symbol like that:

```
m = re.findall("((http:|https:)//[^ \<]*[^ \<\.])",line)
```

Comment: Wow, I definitely did not think of that. Very simple solution. Thanks!