# links in the string do not enable in html code

Tags: html

I'm new to web development, any help from the forum really appreciated!!

I'm reading the text from multiple text files and sending it to a html form as a list.

The text may have some links. These links are not enabled when it is diplayed as a paragraph.
I cannot read each file and put href attributs where ever a link present.

So need help in making below snip enable a link.

> 

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading </h1>
<pre>My first paragraph. https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elements</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot read each file and put href attributs where ever a link present.

Back up your text files first and consider using `sed` from the command line to experiment with automatically adding html to the links within each txt file:

`sed -i -e "s|http[:]//[^ ]*|<a href=\"\0\">\0</a>|g" yourfile.txt` [1]

In the above example, `yourfile` would be replaced with the name of the text file you're working with. If the results look promising, you could update the `sed` command to modify all txt files in a specific location.

Good luck.

---

[1] [Convert URLs into HTML links using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489731/convert-urls-into-html-links-using-sed)